# Efficient way of sorting one column by other column

Tags: sql, .net-core

I got a problem with designing an efficient way of sorting one table by sorted other table.

I got a `Customer` which has a `LicenceId` and `Country`, `Licence` table has column `Name`. I want to display top 1000 customers sorted by Licence name where `Country = "DK"`.

There are more than 10k `licences` and more than 1M customers.

My initial idea was to sort Licences and store them in `Dictionary<string, int>` where key is a `Name` and value is an index of ordered elements. Then create a `Min Heap` with capacity of 1000 and add customers to the heap with the usage of those sorted indexes. Which would result in `O(nlog(n)) + O(mlog(1000)` (n - #licences, m - #customers).

But when it comes to implementing it in SQL I'm facing some issues with loading customers data to memory (~100MB) which slows down the process and sorting on the whole customers table in SQL is also no that super fast. Are there any faster solutions?

Comment: The database can sort data far, **far** more efficiently than any client. 100MB is no data at all. Neither is 1M rows. A `Dictionary` is a naive single-column index implementation compared to a database index. Single-machine servers can handle TB-sized databases and have far more and faster cores, RAM and disks than any client.  If your queries are slow, the problem is the query and the tables. Most likely, there are some missing indexes. If you run your query it's quite likely SQL Server will emit a warning with the missing indexes

Comment: Besides, your code has no idea what values are stored, so it has no way to decide whether one join or sort algorithm will be faster than another (hashing? sort and merge? loop on one side?), or whether parallel execution could improve performance. The server keeps statistics that allow it to determine how many rows and how many distinct values there are, so it can pick the most efficient execution plan

Comment: `Dictionary` is faster than database index. It doesn't create a tree structure and have `O(1)` lookup time. The creation of a tree is also slower as well as inserting elements. So saying that `Dictionary` is a naive implementation is worth rephrasing. About the code and handling joins then it can be easily solved but that an implementation detail (maybe even introduce another `Dictionary` with mapping between Id and Name). What I was striving toward was a solution for effective query but I heard from you that I should trust SQL which in my opinion is a little blind guess instead of analysis.

Comment: `Dictionary is faster than database index.` no it's not, not by a long shot. All the assumptions are wrong. Even that `O(1)` is wrong. Even for plain dictionary access. An *array* is `O(1)`. A dictionary needs to calculate the key hash, find the appropriate bucket then linearly check all items in that bucket. Even the assumption that you can use only one construct. What if the results are already sorted? You could merge them in a single pass instead of looking up every item in a loop. Never mind that you don't know *which* data set to loop unless you know the actual counts

Comment: Calculation of hash takes `O(1)` and the probability of landing in the same bucket for 20k-30k elements is low. Even if we would have a bucket then it would be small. Reads would be on average faster than `log(n)` for trees and writing to tree `nlog(n)`. If elements are sorted than it would be still one pass through the array `O(n)`, same as sorting sorted array

Comment: Not only are those calculations wrong, you forget to include the time to load or *update* the data. The operations you compare aren't the same either. `O(1)` to calculate a hash is orders of magnitude slower than accessing an array location or comparing two values. Saying something is `O(1)` is meaningless when the 1s aren't the same. Instead of making assumptions, create a *proper* benchmark that measures the overall performance over a period of time. You can't just say you run a query 1000 times. Database servers use caching extensively. Quite often the data will already be in the cache.

Comment: You also need to take into account the network overhead. Loading 1M rows over the network isn't trivial *and will impact all other clients* of that server. There's a reason database benchmarks never run on the server itself nor use a single machine.

Comment: Going even further, if you only care about reporting, the database server can use columnstore indexes that take A LOT LESS memory than dictionaries while "indexing" multiple columns at once. Dictionaries don't scale - 1M rows is a lot for a dictionary, not-a-lot for a table. For columnstore indexes though, 1M rows is the *minimum delta size*. Measure real scenarios before making assumptions

Comment: You said that hashing is not `O(1)` and it is. Different time executions for different `O(1)` scenarios are different things. And then you say that saying its `O(1)` is meaningless. I can't trust your words if they are saying one thing in one post and another thing in another. Calculating 1M hashes with MD5 is taking ~627ms and from your speculations, I can conclude that calculating hashes is expensive but from the benchmark, I can clearly see that it is not. Loading 1M rows have been mentioned in the question as the main obstacle. Please read carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would start by writing the SQL query:

```
select c.*, l.licensename
from customers c join
     licenses l
     on c.licenseid = l.licenseid
where c.country = 'DK'
order by l.licensename
fetch first 1000 rows only;
```

Then you would let the optimizer do the work.  In this case, you probably want indexes on `customers(country, licenseid)` and `licenses(licenseid, licensename)` -- although the second is probably there if `licenseid` is declared as the primary key.

Don't worry about microoptimizations.  That is the job of the SQL optimizer.

Comment: Thanks :)  What about the sorting here? Does it sort a whole joined `Customer-Licence`?

Comment: @Pawel . . . It sorts the records that match the `join` and `where` conditions.  It becomes rather tricky if to optimize if you want columns from both tables.

Comment: @Pawel If you want to see what happens, check the execution plan. The server will use the data statistics and the availability of indexes to come up with the most efficient execution plan. If the data is sorted for example, there's no need to explicitly sort again. The indexes *are* sorted, so the server could use a merge join *only if the overall query would be cheaper based on the statistics*. If parallelism is used though, the data may have to be sorted in the end.